# python , subprocess , how to print everything into file, not on shell

Tags: python, shell

First I want to say I have tried to search the answer, but not one is about my problem. -_-!

I have try to use something like:

```
with open("printing.dat","a") as sdtout:    
   sub=subprocess.Popen(command,cwd=modpath,shell=True, stdout=sdtout)
```

To some distance it works. However, my prblem is like this: I use python script to complie my fortran code (thus the command is somthing like "ifort f.f90 -o ..."). When there are some mistakes in fortran code, the complier will return some error information and this part are always printed on shell but not in file. 
  Anyway, if there is no mistakes in fortran code thus the compling is correct, all the printing information from exe(subprocess of script) can be found in stdout file.
  Thanks.

Comment: may be set stderr=sdtout as well.

Comment: Oh yes. you are right. Amazing!!!^_^ Thank you so much.

Comment: @gipsy, could you post your comment as an answer so hengyue can mark it as solved?

Comment: @SB87 Done. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add stderr to your Popen call and set it to your sdtout file

```
with open("printing.dat","a") as sdtout:    
   sub=subprocess.Popen(command,cwd=modpath,shell=True, stdout=sdtout, stderr=sdtout)
```